# Rails - ActiveRecord - How to select one column from one child record based on property of child record which is not the foreign key/primary key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm looking to select all users and I want the zip code of their primary address.

```
class User
  has_many :addresses
end

class Address
  belongs_to :user
  # primary :bool
  # zip_code :string
end
```

At this point, I've gone through dozens of pages that explain joining on the foreign key.

Ideal usage would be something like:

```
User.all.each do  # zipcode needs to get pulled in here
  puts "u.zip_code"
end
```

Comment: User.joins(:addresses).includes(:addresses).where(addresses: {primary: true}).each  do |u| puts u.addresses.first.zip_code end

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use joins in here, you can use `includes` for eager loading the addresses to solve this:

```rb
User.all.include(:addresses).where(addresses: {primary: true}).each do |u|
   # Assumes maximum one primary address by user and will return null if user doesn't have one
   puts u.addresses&.first&.zip_code
end
```